# Instruments for memory leaks with Xcode 4.3.2 quits unexpectedly

Tags: ios, xcode, memory, instruments, memory-leaks

I recieved "recieved memory warning" when I was debugging my application via Xcode Device Debugger. My app doesn't seem to be consuming that much memory, so I wanted to look at Instruments tool for the first time.

My project is on my iphone device. (Generated by xcode when I debugged)
I am currently using Xcode 4.3.2.

BaseSDK: 5.0.1(Latest)

Target Deployment: 5.0

Device Software: 5.0.1 (9A405)

Steps I follow (don't know If I am doing it right though)

I open Instruments Tool, Select Memory Leaks Scheme for iOS, Choose Target (my device), again choose target and my application (which is created by xcode from last build). When I press record button, application launches with no problem, but when application is launching up, Instruments tool quits.(application on my device keeps on running).

I feel that I am not doing something properly. And one more question. My baseSDK is 5.1 but I am targeting on a 5.0.1 device. Is this also a problem?

***Profiling works great on iOS Simulator 5.1, but not on my iPhone.***

***Edit:***
I have also tried profile launch, both set to debug and release. Both crushes the Instruments Tool as well.

Comment: Have you tried doing this by launching the process from Xcode, choosing "Profile" from the "Product" menu?

Comment: @RobertRyan yes, I tried it by setting profile settings both to debug and release, all ends up crashing instruments tool.

Comment: My suggestion was for you to change how you start Instruments. Instead of the process you outline in your original question, try selecting "Profile" from Xcode's "Product" menu.

Comment: well, that didn't helped. It works perfectly on the simulator as I state. And I rebooted my MAC, XCode and phone. All same.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. I thought the issue was a general profiling problem, not specific to profiling on a device. Thanks for the clarification. Given that I always profile in the simulator, I'll defer the device-specific profiling issues to others.

Comment: Based on assumption that leaks are leaks no matter what you work on (an iDevice or iOS simulator), maybe I should give up trying profiling on iDevice and go with simulator.